# online resources for spatial analysis

Tags: spatial

I am wondering about some good online resources for learning how to implement spatial statistical techniques, like Moran's I and Geary's C, or even K Nearest Neighbors...any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/12201/751

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "implement"?  Are you seeking information about how to apply and interpret these techniques, or about algorithms for implementing them yourself in computer code?

Comment: I am seeking resources for both, preferably in R @whuber

Answer (score 1):

**Spatial Regression Models**, by Michael D. Ward and Kristian Skrede Gleditsch is an exellent short introduction. Moran's I is explained on p.23.

**Applied Spatial Data Analysis with R** by Bivand, Pebesma, Gomez-Rubio is a popular choice for doing spatial modelling in R.

In terms packages, R , as usual, has many packages to do all sorts of spatial analysis. One package that computes Moran's I is ape
For spatial kringing and the likes: gstat, akima, fields, gss